# How should I insert values into table with out truncation of zeros in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, zero, truncation

I got a table EMPLOYEE1 and i'm trying to insert values into it

```
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE1 values(00001, 00004566)
```

But it inserts the values as 1 and 4566 truncating zero's why does this happen. can some one help me out

Comment: You must to store such values as string value, not numeric, for saving zeros.

Comment: As a number, `1` and `00001` are equivalent - so SQL Server just stores `1` as a number. Makes sense. If you need to **display** that `1` as `00001` somewhere - do this display formatting where you need it - **in your front-end** (or report or wherever you need it) - don't store this into the database - no need and no benefit from doing so! `1` is just `1` - no matter how many zeroes you add infront of it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because the data type of this column is numeric. You should make these columns varchar to be able to insert numbers without trancating zeros. Something like:

```
CREATE TABLE Employee1(EmpNumber VARCHAR(50), EmpName VARCHAR(50), ...);

INSERT INTO Employee1 VALUES
('00001', 'Foo', ..);
```